# Angular 12 import json into ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I have a json file into `src/assets/version.json` with this content:

```
{"VERSION":"1.0.0"}
```

and I import the file into the `*.ts`, eg.:

```
import * as VersionInfo from 'src/assets/version.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

 constructor() {
   console.log(`version ${VersionInfo['VERSION']}`);
 }

}
```

output

```
version 1.0.0
```

This works on Angular 11 but on Angular 12 the CLI show the error

```
Should not import the named export 'VERSION' (imported as 'VersionInfo') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)
```

this is my tsconfig.base.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es2015",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "jszip": [
        "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  },
}
```

How fix this error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Following should be placed in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
 ...
 "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true, //already there
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true // Add this line
    ...
   },
...
}
```

and then simply import the following in your component

```
import VersionInfo from 'src/assets/version.json';
```

Comment: allowSyntheticDefaultImports should be inside compilerOptions

Comment: @atlau is correct about 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' placement. Also, 'esModuleInterop' is not necessary to add.

Answer (score 7):

You can try in the `tsconfig.json` as:

```
"compilerOptions": { "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true }
```

And import:

```
import VersionInfo from 'src/assets/version.json';
```

Comment: Of all answers, this is only entirely correct one

Answer (score 7):

`import { default as VersionInfo } from 'src/assets/version.json';`

You need the two tsconfig entries mentioned above too.