# How do I read a local JSON file in Angular 12?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to read data from a local JSON file, that stores some config data for my app. I keep getting an error when using the `ng build` [command in the Angular CLI](https://angular.io/cli/build).

The TypeScript file for my component: my-component.ts

```
...
import credentials from './config/credentials.json';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    // Properties
    username: string = credentials.username;
    ...
}
```

The JSON config file, stored at the location '/config': credentials.json

```
{
    "credentials" : {
        "username" : "my_user_name",
        ...
    }
}
```

I am getting the error: `Error: Should not import the named export 'credentials' (imported as 'credentials') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)`

What is causing this error? It seems similar to the [issue described here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20753).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two additional things you need to do for Angular version 12.

First, you need to add some lines to the file. [Reference this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67572896/angular-12-import-json-into-ts). NOTE: these are different than Angular version 11.

```
{
    ...
        "compilerOptions": {
            ...
            "resolveJsonModule": true, // add this line...
            "esModuleInterop": true, // this line...
            ...
        },
    ...
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true // and this line, notice this one is outside of "compiler options"
}
```

Second, you need to add a `let` statement. The above didn't work for me alone, but by also taking this step, I got it to work. [Reference this blog post](https://jones.bz/using-json-modules-in-angular-12/).

The TypeScript file for my component: my-component.ts

```
...
import credentials from './config/credentials.json';

let my_username = credentials.username;  // ADD THIS LINE

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    // Properties
    username: string = my_username; // NOW USE THE NEW VARIABLE
    ...
}
```

Admittedly I do not fully understand *why* this works, but it works. [This source](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/let/) seems to suggest it has to do with variable scoping.